# Top Down recursive in python main function

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to work on Top-down Recursive Descent.
Please take a look at the code first.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
wlist = fname.read().split()
mitr = iter(wlist)
lookahead = bvm()
k()

def bvm():
  #here is the statement

def k():
   #here is the statement
```

I have defined the function bvm() and k() below, but I am trying to call the function on the top-down approach. I get error while trying to call that method.

Is there main method in python so I can call the bvm() and k() method from main method?

Thank you

Comment: You just need to move your function definitions up above the point at which they are first called.

Comment: `fname.read()` isn't going to work. Strings don't have a `read` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define your function before it is called, and you do that by placing the definition above the code where you will call it:

```
def bvm():
  #here is the statement

def k():
  #here is the statement

fname = input("Enter file name: ")
wlist = fname.read().split()
mitr = iter(wlist)
lookahead = bvm()
k()
```

As Python is an interpreted language, it runs the code from top to down, line by line.